# Word for "Writing phrase on something"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

Is there a word that represents the act of writing a phrase on something? In this case, I'm trying to advertise a club by "engraving" or "inking" ping pong balls with a phrase such as "Join this club."

Engraving is close, but you can't engrave ping pong balls, and "inking" is close but doesn't sound right.

Comment: *Branding* is the typical term for vendor giveaways and tschotskes. You could also use the specific method employed, like *screening* or *silk screening*.

Comment: If you are using a mechanized process to mark each object, you can call it "_printing_ [a message or slogan or company name on]"; if not, you might refer to it as "_hand-lettering_ [a message or slogan or company name on]."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about ***inscribe***?

> 2. to mark (a surface) with words, characters, etc., especially in a durable or conspicuous way.   ([m-w.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inscribe?s=t))

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a word but it might be a little over the top!

[emblazon](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=emblazon)

> /ɪmˈbleɪz(ə)n,ɛm-/
>
> verb
>
> conspicuously inscribe or display a design on. "T-shirts emblazoned
>   with the names of baseball teams"

Comment: The word *inscribe* from the definition you quote might actually be precisely what OP is looking for.